# Mongoose group by an lookup with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have two schema's , first one is Quiz and the other one is quizResults, I want to get aggregated data from the quizResult while doing the lookup in quiz Schema. Below is my Quiz schema:

```
vidId: {type: Number, required: true},
status: {type: Number,  enum: [statusType.quizStatusEnums.LIVE, statusType.quizStatusEnums.DELETED], default: statusType.quizStatusEnums.LIVE},
questions: [
    {
        questionNum: { type: Number },
        questionName: { type: String },
        answers: [
            {
                answerId: { type: String, default: uuid.v4() },
                answerName: { type: String },
                isCorrect: { type: Boolean },
                answerType: { type: Number,  enum: [statusType.quizTypeEnums.QUIZ, statusType.quizTypeEnums.SURVEY], default: statusType.quizTypeEnums.QUIZ},
                hotspotId: { type: Number },
                overlayId: {type: Number},
                panelId: {type: String}
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

The Second one is QuizResults: The aggregation query needs to be performed on this collection.

```
  created: {
    type: Date,
},
vidId: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
},
viewerId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
quizId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'quiz'
},
questionId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'quiz'
},
answerId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
isCorrect: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
},
whenAnswered: {
    type: Date
},
```

I want the final aggregated result like that:

```
  [
{
  "questionNum": 2,
  "questionName": "Which is the best selling record in history ?",
  "correct": 10,
  "incorrect": 20,
  "totalAnswers": 30,
  "answers": [
    {
      "answerId": "123abc",
      "answerName": "Thriller Michel Jackson",
      "numResponses": 10
    },
    {
      "answerId": "234d",
      "answerName": "A kind of Magic Queen",
      "numResponses": 10
    },
    {
      "answerId": "432e",
      "answerName": "help The Beatles",
      "numResponses": 10
    }
  ]
},
{
  "questionNum": 1,
  "questionName": "What value has the number PI?",
  "correct": 5,
  "incorrect": 3,
  "totalAnswers": 8,
  "answers": [
    {
      "answerId": "111",
      "answerName": "3.12",
      "numResponses": 0
    },
    {
      "answerId": "222",
      "answerName": "3.14",
      "numResponses": 5
    },
    {
      "answerId": "333",
      "answerName": "3.16",
      "numResponses": 3
    }
  ]
}
 ]
```

What I tried is :

```
    aggregate([
        { "$match": { "vidId": 8225342, } },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$questionId",
            
                "Correct": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": ["$isCorrect", true] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    },
                },
                "Incorrect": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": ["$isCorrect", false] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "quiz",
                "let": { "id": "$_id" },
                "pipeline": [
                    { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$$id", "$questions._id"] } } },
                    { "$unwind": "$questions" },
                    { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$questions._id", "$$id"] } } },

                ],
                "as": "quizData"
            }
        },

        { $unwind: '$quizData' },
        
        { "$project": {
            "questionName": "$quizData.questions.questionName", 
        "questionNum": "$quizData.questions.questionNum",
        "Correct": "$Correct",
        "Incorrect": "$Incorrect", 
        "answers": "$quizData.questions.answers" } },
    ])
```

I got the results something like that:

```
    {
    "_id": "611632305bd3910929b95552",
    "questionName": "Which is the best selling record in history?",
    "questionNum": 5,
    "Correct": 3,
    "Incorrect": 0,
    "answers": [
        {
            "answerId": "078f441b-373f-40e9-89e1-04fca0a9fc5d",
            "answerType": 0,
            "_id": "611632305bd3910929b95553",
            "answerName": "Thriller Michel Jackson",
            "isCorrect": true,
            "hotspotId": 470114,
            "overlayId": 3,
            "panelId": "12abc"
        },
        {
            "answerId": "644b80fe-5778-46fa-b3a6-1eff5989cdee",
            "answerType": 0,
            "_id": "611632305bd3910929b95554",
            "answerName": "A kind of Magic Queen",
            "isCorrect": false,
            "hotspotId": 470113,
            "overlayId": 4,
            "panelId": "12345abc"
        },
        {
            "answerId": "5bde2682-66fe-4c79-a728-aea67f6842a8",
            "answerType": 0,
            "_id": "611632305bd3910929b95555",
            "answerName": "help The Beatles",
            "isCorrect": false,
            "hotspotId": 470112,
            "overlayId": 3,
            "panelId": "12abc"
        }
    ]
},
```

how I can get the Answers array like that:

```
 answers: [
                {
                    answerId: "123abc",
                    answerName: "Thriller Michel Jackson",
                    numResponses: 10
                },  
                 {
                    answerId: "234d",
                    answerName: "A kind of Magic Queen",
                    numResponses: 10
                },
                {
                    answerId: "432e",
                    answerName: "help The Beatles",
                    numResponses: 10
                }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to approach it the other way around. Use `$lookup` to get `quizResults` filtered and aggregated and then run [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) along with [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to get matching statistics for each answer:

```
db.quiz.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "vidId": 8225342 }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "quizResults",
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { "vidId": 8225342 } },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$answerId",
                        count: { $sum: 1 }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "quizResults"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            questions: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$questions",
                    as: "q",
                    in: {
                        _id: "$$q._id",
                        questionName: "$$q.questionName",
                        questionNum: "$$q.questionNum",
                        answers: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$$q.answers",
                                as: "a",
                                in: {
                                    $mergeObjects: [
                                        "$$a",
                                        {
                                            $let: {
                                                vars: {
                                                    fst: {
                                                        $first: { 
                                                            $filter: { input: "$quizResults", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$$a._id" ] } }
                                                        } 
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                in: { numResponses: "$$fst.count" }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KRLAZJ0eLE5)

Comment: I have just updated my question, I am Expecting the answers array with the sum of each answer, how many times each answer was given.

Comment: @BilalMaher would you be able to create a Mongo Playground with a bit of your sample data for expected result?

Comment: Thanks for your comment I have created a mongo play ground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/E4_0WYh3hpW

Comment: @BilalMaher thank you, that was really helpful, modified my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for making that query can you please add the working mongo playground. I am not able to run the query that you pasted here.

Comment: @BilalMaher sure, you can check it out here, there are two responses for `3.14` https://mongoplayground.net/p/KRLAZJ0eLE5

Comment: The query you made, seems to be wrong, there is only one response for 3.14. while the query returning 2 responses. 
and also I have to do the query on quizResults .

Comment: @BilalMaher I have added one more to sample data - you can find it based on anwerId

Comment: If you look at my query it is giving the right data with right formatting, the only issue i am getting is to calculate the total number of responses for each answerId in the answers array.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/rskQxdifogZ

Comment: If we can add one more group ( group by answerId and add the count for each anserId) in the same query than I think the problem will be solved but for that I have no idea, how to add one more group, weather using $facet or something else ??

Comment: Is this what you need: https://mongoplayground.net/p/N2Hivutebdf ?

Comment: Tha data is correct, but my question is why we have to do it with other way( query on quiz model instead of quizResults), 
Why cant we achieve that while querying on the quizResults Model ?

Comment: Also, this query is giving error in Robo 3T shell, I am not able to run it.

Failed to execute script.

Error: command failed: {
 "operationTime" : Timestamp(1629143731, 76),
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$first'",
 "code" : 168,
 "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator",
 "$clusterTime" : {
  "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1629143731, 77),
  "signature" : {
   "hash" : BinData(0,"PHg3nyw/3I57LCrnG1PldIp1SUY="),
   "keyId" : NumberLong("6945018046696128515")
  }
 }
} : aggregate failed 
Details:
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13

Comment: @BilalMaher you can use `$arrayElemAt` instead of `$first` - your MongoDB version doesn't recognize `$first` as it was introduced recently

Comment: can you please update the mongo Playground with $arrayElemAt , i am still getting error.

Comment: @BilalMaher here you go: https://mongoplayground.net/p/6RQsUpYS31L

Comment: My actual requirement was the data to be look like this:  **paste.ofcode.org/iFQ6aCbwCLL4CMTj8vRCCp**
I have pasted the final json in my question and also here in the link.

Comment: Data is not correct, can you please make the query that gives the response like the one i am expecting >